# Parameter is not valid - Bitmap constructor error

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, bitmap

I am trying to initiate a new `Image` object here:

```
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(21241,21241);
```

The overloaded constructor that i intend to use is [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7we6s1x3(v=vs.110).aspx) one:

```
public Bitmap(
    int width,
    int height
)
```

I do understand that the value `21241` is a bit but still under the `int` range than why it says invalid parameter?

Already check this answers:

- [Parameter is not valid error on bitmap constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10148261/parameter-is-not-valid-error-on-bitmap-constructor)
  *Cant do because i dont have an image i am creating one which i have to than fill using `Graphics.FromImage(image);*

Comment: You are probably running the process out of memory with that.

Comment: Checkt this out - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/37684999-62c7-4c41-8167-745a2b486583/systemdrawingbitmap-max-size?forum=netfxbcl . Most probably memory issue. In theory you should be able to set both values up to `Int32.Max` but in practice this seems to cause problems.